# select words excluding some specific ones - regular expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match words from a sentence excluding the ones start with `@`.

The original pattern which does not exclude the words starting with `@` is the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> token_pattern_o='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'
>>> re.search(token_pattern_o, "@mutt")
<re.Match object; span=(1, 5), match='mutt'>
```

Now I am just adding a negative lookahead for the exclusion:

```
>>> token_pattern = '(?u)\\b^(?!@)\\w\\w+\\b'
>>> re.search(token_pattern, "#mutt")
>>> re.search(token_pattern, "@mutt")
>>> re.search(token_pattern, "mutt")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='mutt'>
>>> re.search(token_pattern, "_mutt")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='_mutt'>
```

The issue is, it is excluding every word starting with any special character.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the following instead:

```
token_pattern = '(?u)\\b(?<!@)\\w\\w+\\b'
```

That said, please do me a favour:

```
token_pattern = r'(?u)\b(?<!@)\w\w+\b'
```

Comment: Wow! Could you please explain a bit as to how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the character or exclude the entire word?

```
import re

patt = re.compile(r'[^@]\w*')

print(patt.search('mutt'))
print(patt.search('#mutt'))
print(patt.search('@mutt'))
print(patt.search('%mutt'))
print(patt.search('^mutt'))
```

will give this output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='#mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(1, 5), match='mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='%mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='^mutt'>
```

Changing the pattern to:

```
patt = re.compile(r'[^@]?\w*')
```

will provide this output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='#mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='%mutt'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='^mutt'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to match a single word charactere,  and assert what is on the left is not an `@`.

If that is the case, match 1+ word chars and use word boundaries at the beginning and the end of the pattern.

```
(?u)\b\w(?<!@\w)\w+\b
```

In parts

- `(?u)` Inline flag for unicode (or use `re.U`)
- `\b` Word boundary
- `\w` Match a word char
- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not

  - `@\w` Match @ and a single word char
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JKlhBh/1)